# Batch script to output git sha1id to a #define in header file

Tags: windows, git, batch-file, echo

I would like to create a batch script that can insert the current git sha1-id as a "#define" in a header file. I want the batch script to basically create (and overwrite) this new header file, that header file should look like this:

`#define GIT_VERSION "0cdf35j"`

I would like that #define to show exactly as displayed above: single line and with the double quotes so I can use it as a string in my code.

I can use the 'echo' command to print out the "#define GIT_VERSION", and I can use the "git describe --always --dirty" command to get the actual sha1-id. The problem is putting those two together and have that whole output appear on the same line in the header file. The issue I continue to have is the new line characters that get output by the "echo" and "git describe" commands. I also struggle to get those double quotes to show correctly.

When I try this:

```
(echo | set /p = #define GIT_VERSION & echo ^")>git_version.h
git describe --always --dirty>>git_version.h
echo ^">>git_version.h
```

I get this (close but just need it to be in a single line):

```
#define GIT_VERSION "
5711634-dirty
"
```

How can I eliminate those pesky new line characters so that #define shows up on the same line? If you could include working batch code in your answer, that would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Can you try with `echo -n`?

Comment: Have you tried a simple `-n` for your echos?

Comment: But I think you will be better served by doing `echo "#define GIT_VERSION \"$( git describe ..... )\" > git_version.h` or something along those lines.

Comment: Agreed with @eftshift0 (as often!), you'd be better off constructing a unique echo with command substitution.

Comment: For those that mentioned echo -n, that "-n" option does not seem to be supported by the echo function. I've tried that in various different ways. I tried the suggestion by @eftshift0 but that didn't work, I think the double quotes after the echo doesn't work.

Comment: It should work, just find a way to make echo understand that you want to write a `"`. I think this should be close enough: `echo '#define GIT_VERSION "' $( git command )'"'` (worked for me!). And about `-n`, I guess it depends on which `echo` you are using.

Comment: Thanks @eftshift0, I tried your suggestion exactly as you provided and it's not working quite right. I tried this ```echo '#define GIT_VERSION "' $( git describe --always )'"'>git_version.h``` and I got this ```'#define GIT_VERSION "' $( git describe --always )'"'```.
I always figured out that echo like ^" in order to print the double quotes but I can't seem to get rid of the new lines. However, I think I eventually found a different way to solve it. I'll post that answer on here shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution using a method that is - how should I say - not entirely sanctioned by stackoverflow (and I'll leave it at that and hope I don't get into too much trouble). That method generated the following answer:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('git describe --always --dirty') do set git_version=%%a

set "output_file=git_version.h"

echo #define GIT_VERSION "%git_version%" > %output_file%
```

I tried running that batch script and I verified that the answer works for me and outputs exactly what I wanted:

```
#define GIT_VERSION "5711634-dirty"
```

Comment: ChatGPT policy: https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy